# polyfit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'w'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use `np.polyfit` and I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: polyfit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'w'
```

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) on that function clearly mentions this argument so I'm not sure whats going on. I'm using `SciPy 0.12.0` and `NumPy 1.6.1`.

Here's a MWE that returns that error:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
weight = np.array([0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3])

poli = np.polyfit(x, y, 3, w=weight)
```

Comment: Working fine for me: `np.polyfit(x, y, 3, w=weight)`
Out: `array([ 0.07560951, -0.73588568,  1.60981722, -0.12172434])`

Comment: Works with `numpy==1.7.1`

Comment: Perhaps its `numpy` then, I'm using version 1.6.1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) for your numpy version, the argument 'w' was only introduced in a later version.

Comment: Thanks, off to upgrade numpy then.

Comment: @Gabriel After you upgrade, you may consider switching to use [`from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as poly`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) and [`poly.polyfit(x, y, 3, ...)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)

Comment: @askewchan I'll do that as soon as I am able to upgrade. Apparently it is not that simple :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839488/cant-upgrade-numpy-on-ubuntu-12-04